# Cannot drag tabs in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, drag-and-drop

I used to be able to drag tabs in Internet Explorer, and even drag and drop tabs beteen different top-level Windows.   For some reason this stopped working and now I am unable to drag tabs.

Is there any configuration setting that enables / disables this feature?

Answer (score 0):

My checking did not turn up a setting for disabling the ability to drag a tab. You can try resetting IE back to default and see if that rectifies it. Hit Alt-X to enter the tool menu, go to Internet Options -> advanced -> and click the reset button on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that hitting "ESC" fixes the issue.   At least until the next time.

Answer (score -1):

wow thanks for that John,  this was driving me mad trying to figure it out!  so many other similar questions with either no answer, or pointing to regedit (where the fields to edit don't exist)

My first reaction to your seemingly too simple answer was "Really?"  Promptly went to my glitching IE, and lo and Behold, [ESC] key worked in making tabs movable again.  I don't think I ever would have figured it out except by pure luck.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Super User way of saying thank you.